# Why magento installation hangs on configuration phase?

Tags: magento-1.8, installation

I am done with all what i can do to figure out why magento installation hangs on configuration phase. I did everything what is given here: http://www.ironion.com/installing-magento-on-xampp/

But even then I am stuck on configuration wile installing magento. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Please explain at which point of the installation this happens and what "hanging" exactly means. 
You can also check your server configuration with this file, maybe there's something missing: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Comment: Are you checking php myadmin tables parallely, i guess you are checking on the step where the database table are created.

Comment: I had the same issue, After giving the port number with database host my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing on localhost your configuration should look like

```
Database type: MySQL
Host: localhost
Database name: your_database_name
Username: {usually root}
Password: your_password {usually no password so leave blank}
```

And hit NEXT!

Comment: Not going through. Still hanging.

Comment: And what do you mean by hanging?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was solved by ticking this option in db configuration:

Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is pointing to **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost** in Host field.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things worth trying that haven't yet been mentioned:

In your Windows hosts file, add the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
localhost 127.0.0.1
```

In your .htaccess file change the `php_value memory_limit` to a higher value. Remember to restart apache after making these changes before trying a new installation.